# Noun for "person with intermediate skill"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for the noun form of "person with intermediate skill". For example, in the context of a particular activity, "person with no skill" might be designated a *novice*, and "person with much skill" might be designated an *expert*. However I know of no such word in between these two extremes.

My only thought is *amateur*, which has a distinct meaning from describing level of skill, although skill level can often be inferred. I'm looking for a better solution.

**EDIT**: due to the attention this question has received, I'll try to offer some clarification in order to reduce repeat questions.

1. "Journeyman" would certainly not work. I am a software developer by profession. However the word I'm looking for should hopefully be profession-agnostic.
2. I am trying to designate the skill level of the person that some learning material might be appropriate for. The word that I'm looking for follows the preposition "for".

   - `For Beginners`
   - `For [word for intermediate-skilled person]`
   - `For Experts`
3. Sorry, but even after all the great answers, I'm still learning towards "amateur" even though it is technically incorrect. Also, the word should not be so esoteric that only people with English degrees know what it means. Keep the ideas coming!

Comment: What skill or activity is it that you want to characterize? That can make a difference.

Comment: Let's say it's a professional software developer. Someone who writes software for computers. Professional developers are not equally skilled at all programming languages. The terms "journeyman" or "dabbler" would hardly seem appropriate here.

Comment: "Journeyman software developer" would be good and appropriate usage, especially with the craftsman-like aspects of being a developer. Certainly people are much more aware of its craft-like aspects than they were ten years ago.

Comment: @jprete: except you'll get strange looks and confused faces from other software developers if you used the phrase "journeyman software developer"

Comment: @Lie: I do not believe that is true. I've used it at work, albeit infrequently, and people understood what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Opinions obviously differ. I agree "journeyman software developer" sounds odd. Partly because it already sounds "dated" to me, with [usage increasingly falling](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=journeyman&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), so it hardly suits a modern skill such as software development.  Partly because I think it associates [more with manual trades](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=journeyman+artist%2Cjourneyman+carpenter&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) rather than cerebral/creative ones.

Comment: @jprete: I think your assertion that software development is more recognised as *craftsmanlike* today is just wishful thinking. I started in the 70s, when there were no degrees in computer science. Most of us had degrees in English or History - it was very unusial to find yourself working alongside anyone with a degree in maths or any other "hard science". Software was largely recognised as an "arcane art" back then. If anything it's become more downgraded over the decades, as managers assume all the clever stuff is in the "rapid development" tools we've got nowadays.

Comment: What is the context this word would be used in?

Comment: How about manager?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In some professional organizations, the word "Journeyman" is used for someone who has passed their apprenticeship and able to complete work on their own, but are not necessarily masters yet.

**EDIT:** If you are seeking a skill level reference for learning material.  This seems to be a standard:

```
For Beginner [programmers, developers, carpenters, chefs]
For Intermediate [programmers, developers, carpenters, chefs]
For Advanced [programmers, developers, carpenters, chefs]
```

You are asking for a word to replace "intermediate", but the more I think about it "intermediate" may actually be the word you need.

Comment: The problem with *journeyman* is it's profession-specific in that sense. When applied more generally, it does indeed mean *reasonably competent at simple tasks*, but to me at least it has overtones of *but something of a 'plodder', who's unlikely to ever become a master of his craft*.

Comment: I've never, ever heard it used in the context of "a plodder who's unlikely to master the craft", so I don't think that's a universal connotation.

Comment: It's also suitable only for (certain) professional contexts, e.g. a a "journeyman snowboarder" makes no sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But any "task" can be isolated to be a trade itself. . .

Comment: @jprete: I never expected my connotations to be shared by everyone - that's why I said *to me at least*. But I doubt I picked up that connotation out of thin air, so I imagine I'm not alone, even if no-one here on EL&U ever upvotes my comment to that effect.

Comment: I'm with @FumbleFingers on this one. I generally see the word used as a backhanded complement to describe someone who is perhaps competent, but not great. I don't see it used much on people who are presumed to be still learning their craft and show a lot of potential.

Comment: @T.E.D. That's it! - it's often a *backhanded complement*. I know "improver" isn't a standard term in most skill areas, but the meaning is instantly clear. Plus it automatically carries the implication that you will get more skilled. But "journeyman" can easily imply that intermediate level is as good as you're going to get, if only because it doesn't strongly imply future improvement.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't tell that to American union workers. Journeyman in the electricians/tile layers/carpenters unions (in my local at least) is a title they work towards.  Although on a practical level most of those guys stop there, which could be where the "backhandedness" of the compliment comes from? I have personally never heard it used as anything other than neutral.

Comment: @Lee Quarella: If it's a title you work towards, that implies it's a goal, not a staging-post. Which is only really the nuance I've been getting at. A journeyman is still only a tradesman, not a *craftsman*.

Comment: @LeeQuarella - You are right of course. "Journeyman" has a very specific meaning in certian trades, and it is not derogatory. It just implies a certian level of seniority. However, its pretty easy to distinguish when it is being used that way.

Answer (score 22):

There isn't a word that's as widely recognized as *novice* or *expert* that I know, but I would suggest **adept**.

It's far more commonly used as an adjective, but the noun form does exist.

This can apply to professional or non-professional skills. It indicates some level of mastery without necessarily being *expert* (but the meaning seems closer to *expert* than *novice*). I would rank them in this order:

1. novice
2. amateur
3. adept
4. expert

This seems to fit with the various ranks of "[Adept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adept)" that are used by different religious and occult orders.

From Latin, "past participle of *adipisci* to attain, from *ad apisci* to reach" (related to *apt*).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I would place adept and expert at the same level, or possibly even switch adept and expert. To me, adept has a strong connotation of being extremely skilled.

Comment: @JesusFreke yes, I agree the meaning can be unclear and it can seem like a synonym of "expert", but I would be more likely to say someone is "fairly adept" than to try and qualify "expert" at a lesser degree.

Comment: Yeah, good point. "fairly adept" definitely makes more sense than "fairly expert"

Comment: In many games, adept is considered lower than expert (or master). I'm not saying that this is the correct usage, just that is is quite prevalent.

Answer (score 14):

Your question reminds me of the [Dreyfus model of skill acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_model_of_skill_acquisition) which describes five stages in increasing (any particular) skill:

1. Novice
2. Advanced beginner
3. Competent
4. Proficient
5. Expert

Borrowing from that, use of "competent" or "proficient" might be one option. Problem is, "competent" isn't a noun and "proficient", according to NOAD, is only rarely used as such (as in the example *he became a proficient in Latin and Greek*).

Answer (score 8):

"[Journeyman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeyman)" means "someone who completed an apprenticeship and was fully educated in a trade or craft, but not yet a master."  "Apprentice" also may be relevant, but I think can include very tyros as well as persons of some experience.  (While  [sense 1 of tyro](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyro) may apply (1. a learner or beginner;
   2. a freshman or greenhorn) sense 2 does not.)

I've occasionally seen "[sophomore](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophomore)" denoting an intermediate level.  An example from wiktionary: "The band’s sophomore album built upon the success of their debut release".  However, its adjectival form "[sophomoric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophomoric)", "conceited and overconfident of knowledge but poorly informed and immature", may be the opposite of what you're after.

Comment: "Sophomore" in that context doesn't mean "intermediate skill", it means "second attempt".

Answer (score 8):

Based on your edit of how you intend to use these, I would propose:

- For Beginning users
- For **Experienced** users
- For Advanced users

Or possibly:

- For Beginning users
- For **Intermediate** users
- For Advanced users

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the best word to describe someone with an intermediate level of skill is "intermediate."

He is an "intermediate" in the game.

Other words I'd use are "middling" and "competent." That is, neither clumsy nor expert.

Comment: I think you could even say *"an intermediate player"* instead of *"he is intermediate in the game"*.

Answer (score 5):

It's *Junior*. Growing better gets to *Senior*. Even better, near full control? *Expert*. Knows everything? *Master*.

Comment: "Junior" is often synonymous with "novice", while "senior" is often synonymous with "expert", and otherwise they tend to be used in different contexts.

Comment: I agree but i'm not so sure about this too. Let's see what Travis Webb thinks about it in his context... thank's for the editing and the comment. I'm a foreign.

Comment: I wasn't the person who did the edit, that was @kiamlaluno.

Comment: sry @kiamlaluno. kiss principle.

Comment: I was searching a little more, programmers tend to use this kind of terminology. Specially the terms _junior_ and _senior_.

Answer (score 3):

In many professions, such as law and finance, the term **Associate** is used. The term Associate Programmer or Associate Engineer, most would understand, is adept and able but not a high-level expert.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **hobbyist**? It generally implies one has devoted some time to a pursuit but hasn't  mastered it (and perhaps doesn't have the desire to).

Comment: While this makes sense, hobbyist has the same problem of "amateur" that I want to avoid. It only implies skill level, instead of defining it. "Expert" is, in itself, a definition for a level of skill. Hobbyist is only an implication. This is what I'm trying to get away from. It may be the case that no such word exists, which I'd also like to definitively know if that is, in fact, the answer.

Comment: You could also go with 'dabbler'.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I think, though, you would never call an expert a hobbyist - that would be considered patronizing. So its definition might be stricter than you think.

Comment: hobbyist does not convey skill level at all, instead a hobbyist conveys that the person does not use their skill for as their primary source of income but only as a hobby. An expert in a particular field can be a hobbyist, if they do not make a living from the skill.

Answer (score 2):

Not a noun, but competent seems like the word you're looking for...

Answer (score 2):

What about Semi-pro or semi-professional?

Answer (score 1):

I think probably the best word is **improver**. This is (or at least, *was*) a standard term in the UK building industry, applied to newly-qualified apprentices who in principle had the *knowledge* relevant to their trade, but not yet the *experience* to be called a fully-qualified tradesman.

Comment: This is interesting, but have to say I've never heard that used in US.

Comment: @Chinasaur: I just happen to understand it that way because I worked on building sites in the early 70s. Here's a [bit of UK parliamentary debate](http://books.google.com/books?id=LUBNAAAAYAAJ&q=%22is+an+improver%22&dq=%22is+an+improver%22&hl=en&ei=zWJ-TunvHcuv8QOY252lAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCA) from 1900 which I'm sure would be in reference to the word, as applied to multiple trades. But that's just history now. It's a good word for OP because it's self-descriptive (no need to learn/explain), and has no 'dated' connotations for most people.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because of sports usage (a "journeyman reliever"), *journeyman* has assumed negative connotations that would have surprised those who went through an arduous apprenticeship to become a journeyman in their trade or craft in bygone days.

That being said, *mid-level* is a term I've seen used in job listings that accurately describes that vast middle ground between not knowing enough to be useful, and knowing too much to be of any use.

Answer (score 1):

### Practitioner

From the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/practitioner):

> A person actively engaged in an art, discipline, or profession, especially medicine.

Comment: I think Practitioner is a good answer and deserves more visibility so I've proposed an edit giving the ODO definition. I've also dropped the mention of Professional as it is excluded by OP (who favours 'Amateur').

Answer (score 1):

The [Dreyfus Model of Skill Acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_model_of_skill_acquisition) uses the terms "novice", "advanced beginner", "competent", "proficient", and "expert" to describe the level of skill towards a particular task in an individual. What you're describing sounds like either "competent" or "proficient". I'm not familiar with a noun form of "competent" (and dictionaries weren't of much help - there might not be one), but "proficient" can be used as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

*Experienced* would be less skilled than *Expert*.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question searching for an answer to it myself.

I would (humbly) offer "Enthusiast" as a noun for someone with intermediary skill:

Novice, Beginner, **Enthusiast**, Master and Luminary.

I have **Novice** AND **Beginner**, because, for my purposes, I need to draw a distinction between someone who knows NOTHING and someone who's gotten their feet wet (or maybe have waded in up to their crotch). I'm also in the software field (well, web programming) I have done lots of training.

Not only is **Enthusiast** a noun but it also conveys the attitude and eagerness which a **Beginner** must possess in order to meet the challenges of becoming a **Master**.

There is also **Dilettante**, however that carries what to me seems like a negative connotation that they are "interested" but only on a superficial level and only as long as it doesn't interfere with their tennis-playing or trips to Brunei.

Although you didn't ask for it, others reading your question may like to know that another great word (instead of **Luminary**) for a person beyond **Master** is **Doyen**, which means the most respected or prominent person in a particular field.

Answer (score 0):

British English, at least, distinguishes between a skilled labourer, a semi-skilled labourer and an unskilled labourer.

Comment: In American English these refer to classes of jobs. Being a server in a restaurant is _unskilled labor_; even if a server is extremely good the job is still considered _unskilled_. Vice versa, even a terrible programmer is engaged in _skilled labor_.

Comment: -1 user2400's explanation applies to BrE too.