# What do you call the position leveled after Junior, but before Senior in a company?

Tags: business-language

I would like to refer to the intermediate level of a Human Resources Analyst position.

Alice got promoted, so she is not a Junior HR Analyst anymore. However, she is not a Senior HR Analyst yet.

What do you call the position leveled after Junior, but before Senior in which Alice currently is? Considering **Junior is 1** and **Senior is 3**, what would **2** be called?

Comment: Why not use just "HR Analyst"?

Comment: Because there is a payment difference according to the job description. The job descripition is different depending on the quality of knowledge the person has acquired, and the functions he/she practices, as a Junir Analyst, as a Senior Analyst or as the intermediate level i'm trying to discover

Comment: This question is a bit too specific to human resources. Maybe you can generalize it to Junior X and Senior X? Also, are you interested in creating a new position and pay grade between junior and senior? if so, you can call it what you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too localised". Any employer can and will use whatever terminology they like to differentiate between skill levels/areas within the workforce. 25 years ago the company I worked for upgraded all development staff overnight to *senior analyst* or above, simply so it looked better to our clients (and so we could charge more per day for someone who was really just a junior programmer).

Comment: Actually there's nothing specific to Human Resources. The HR Analyst was just an example, but it could have been a Financial Analyst as well. Here in Brazil we have 3 different levels, Junior, "Plene" and Senior, in this order. My doubt was in order to check if there was a matching word in English.

Comment: @Guilherme: It would be best if you specified that in your question.

Comment: Related: [Noun for “person with intermediate skill”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43111/noun-for-person-with-intermediate-skill)

Comment: Since this is marked as duplicate; how can i find the referenced unique (not duplicate) question? I assume it is this one [noun-for-person-with-intermediate-skill](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43111/noun-for-person-with-intermediate-skill). If i remember correctly on stackoverflow the original question would be part of the duplicate block. This would be a nice feature to have. Or can a mod add this link into the block?

Answer (score 5):

Typically, you would have "Junior HR Specialist", "HR Specialist", and then "Senior HR Specialist."

I've also seen it run "HR Specialist Trainee", "HR Specialist 1", "HR Specialist 2" and so on.

You could also call her an "Intermediate HR Specialist" or "[Subaltern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaltern) HR Specialist"

Comment: After living abroad for a while I found out your answer has what I was looking for back then. Thank you very much!

Comment: In the linked question [this answer mentions  **Associate**](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/43204/61620).

Answer (score 1):

There is no word or phrase in English that indicates a level in between 'senior' and 'junior'. It's like saying what is between 1st and 2nd.

However, one can manage this by artificially creating intermediate grades between the two, say, Junior Analyst I and Junior Analyst II.

Comment: Thank you Mitch. I believe these levels are organized a bit different in our languages (English - Brazilian Portuguese).

Comment: @Matt: surely reality is more complex than language. All I'm saying is that in English there is no label for an intermediate degree between Sr and Jr. Brazilian Portuguese does seem to have such an intermediate label.

Comment: Sorry, Mitch, I misread your opening sentence to mean there is nothing between junior and senior.