# What is a single word for "little experience"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which displays more experience than beginner and I do not want to say "intermediate".

Comment: You can try this URL with somewhat the same idea: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37078/what-is-the-word-phrase-for-someone-between-expert-and-novice

Comment: @ChrisAlE That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Before we can suggest an alternative, you need to explain what the problem is with *Intermediate*. What kind of word are you looking for? An adjective?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try to just use inexperienced. If not, you could also try apprentice or trainee.