# Skill Levels - Nomeclature

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'm trying to build an abstract skill level chart to be applied to diverse subjects.

Right now - using only common sense - the list of levels I was able to think is:

- {MISSING} : Don't know anything about it nor have any skill on it.
- Aware : Just know about it, but does not have any skill on it.
- {MISSING} : Has some knowledge but no skill on it.
- Practitioner : Has some knowledge and have a basic skill on it.
- {MISSING} : Has good knowledge and good skill, but haven't master any technique.
- Proficient : Has good knowledge and has skill enough to know one technique.
- Expert : Has a very good knowledge and knows about more than one technique.
- Master : Is a reference on the subject, very deep knowledge and dominates the subject.

As you can see, there is gaps on such skill levels.

Question : Is there any other words that can be placed - or replaced - to have more layers between these levels and encompass more of them on my list?

Comment: You need to define the levels that you think are missing before anyone can suggest names for them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Add more details.

Comment: There are many terms for beginners and many terms for experts, and not many in between, and there is no universally understood ranking of such terms. You can take an existing ranking system and adapt it, or choose terms and define them yourself. Yes, this means in your system, a *tenderfoot* might be more advanced than a *greenhorn* and in another system the opposite, but there is no right and wrong about such things. After all, title escalation has led to a proliferation of dubious *wizards*, *black belts*, *gurus*, *rockstars*, *jedis*, and *ninjas* in recent years.

Comment: Related: 1. [Noun for “person with intermediate skill”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43111/noun-for-person-with-intermediate-skill) 2. [List of expertise levels from beginner to expert](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83832/list-of-expertise-levels-from-beginner-to-expert) and 3. [Word for a person who learned something in the past, but is now back down to beginner level?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313969/word-for-a-person-who-learned-something-in-the-past-but-is-now-back-down-to-beg)

Comment: 4.  [What is the word/phrase for someone between expert and novice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37078/what-is-the-word-phrase-for-someone-between-expert-and-novice) 5. [Term for a person with absolutely zero knowledge of a topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263302/term-for-a-person-with-absolutely-zero-knowledge-of-a-topic)

Comment: 6. [What are common word sets for describing ranks in a profession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/what-are-common-word-sets-for-describing-ranks-in-a-profession?noredirect=1&lq=1) and last but not least 7. [A word for someone who has more skill than a code monkey to be at just the next level](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30758/a-word-for-someone-who-has-more-skill-than-a-code-monkey-to-be-at-just-the-next?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are common word sets for describing ranks in a profession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/what-are-common-word-sets-for-describing-ranks-in-a-profession)

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Novice", "Apprentice", and "Journeyman" in your list. For example:

- Novice: Don't know anything about it nor have any skill on it.
- Amateur : Just know about it, but does not have any skill on it.
- Apprentice : Has some knowledge but no skill on it.
- Journeyman :
  Has some knowledge and have a basic skill on it.
- Practitioner: Has good
  knowledge and good skill, but haven't master any technique.
- Proficient : Has good knowledge and has skill enough to know one
  technique.
- Expert : Has a very good knowledge and knows about more
  than one technique.
- Master : Is a reference on the subject, very deep
  knowledge and dominates the subject.

Comment: The problem with using "amateur" is that it's often used as a term to mean an non-professional and it's entirely possible for such non-professionals to be very skillful indeed.

Comment: This is true. It can also be used as a noun defined as "A person who is contemptibly inept at a particular activity.", or as an adjective "Done in an inept or unskilful way." Both of these definitions come from the Oxford English Dictionary, and are the reasons I used it here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider just using Level 0, Level 1, etc. as you have so many levels. The titles become fairly meaningless with this level of granularity.

Or use fewer levels. For example, one organisation I work for uses (something like) the following:

- **None**:    no experience or real understanding of the technology
- **Low**:     reasonable understanding of the technology, limited experience
- **Medium**:  good level of technical knowledge and experience
- **High**:    deep technical knowledge of the technology, applications and the
  market

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you label your various levels more uniformly, whether as nouns or adjectives, as you did with your three highest levels, all of which are adjectives:

- *proficient* worker
- *expert* worker
- *master* worker

As for some suggestions for your "missing" categories, here are some possibilities, all of which are nouns, except for those with modifying adjectives:

***Level 1:***

- novitiate
- apprentice
- newbie
- novice
- initiate
- trainee
- rookie
- neophyte
- probie, or probationer

***Level 2:***

- apprentice
- learner
- advanced beginner
- semiskilled worker
- amateur
- competent worker

***Level 3:***

- very competent worker
- intermediate-ability worker
- seasoned worker
- accomplished worker
- journeyman
- tradesman
- craftsman